# slow hide event canceled by remove event in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, callback, hide

I have a question about how too keep one event perform an action without being canceled
by the next line off code
In this case, I don't want the remove action to cancel the hidd behavior

Maybe, this falls into the category off callbacks, but I am not sure if I can use it in this case

the code beneath already resides in the callback off a load method

this is the code

```
$(".frmtbnote:last").submit(function () {
    $(this).parents(".paneltbnote").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
    $(this).parents(".wrappertbnote").remove();

    $.post("tbnotesact.php", {
        noteid: $tbnoteid,
        action: "remove",
        time: timestamp
    }, function (xml) {
        // do something
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe a callback is what you are after

```
$(this).parents(".paneltbnote").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow", function(){
    $(this).parents(".wrappertbnote").remove();
  }
);
```